# Limiting keyboard inputs to A-Z as opposed to any keyboard input on React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, keyboard-events, setstate

I've just come across a component I'm struggling to get my head around, but basically the value I care about is `allowForClassification`, which is a boolean value that is passed down into a child component and determines whether or not we display a button. (Basically meaning that only after a user has typed a letter will the "Find" button appear - currently even a spacebar will trigger the button to appear).

However I'm struggling to understand in this component where exactly that check is being made, I understand that at the bottom `allowForClassification` is set to true if `canClassify` & `!classifyInProgress` are returned but I can't find where they are making the check for the keyboard entry, any advice would be really helpful.

```
const getCcceValues = (object?: FormObjectModel | null) => {
  const ccceInput: $Shape<CcceInput> = {};

  if (!object) {
    return {};
  }

  const ccceValues = object.attributeCollection.questions.reduce(
    (acc, attribute) => {
      const fieldEntry = ccceBeInformedFieldMap.get(attribute.key);

      if (fieldEntry) {
        acc[fieldEntry] = attribute.value;
      }

      return acc;
    },
    ccceInput
  );

  // ready to perfom classification based on user input
  const canClassify = Object.values(ccceValues).every(Boolean);

  return { canClassify, ccceValues };
};

export const useCcceEmbed = (
  ccceResultAttribute: AttributeType,
  onChange: Function
): CcceHook => {
  const { object, form } = useFormObjectContext();
  const [resultCode, setResultCode] = useState<string | null>(null);

  const { canClassify, ccceValues } = getCcceValues(object);

  const { handleSubmit } = useFormSubmit();

  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const handleCloseModal = useCallback(() => setShowModal(false), []);
  const handleShowModal = useCallback(() => setShowModal(true), []);

  // state value to keep track of a current active classification
  const [classifyInProgress, setClassifyInProgress] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const handleResult = useCallback(
    (result) => {
      if (result?.hsCode) {
        onChange(ccceResultAttribute, result.hsCode);

        setResultCode(result.hsCode);
        setClassifyInProgress(false);

        handleSubmit(form);
      }
    },
    [ccceResultAttribute, form, handleSubmit, onChange]
  );

  const handleCancelClassify = useCallback(() => {
    setClassifyInProgress(false);
    handleCloseModal();
  }, [handleCloseModal]);

  const handleClassify = useCallback(
    (event?: SyntheticEvent<any>) => {
      if (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("scenario 1");
      }

      if (classifyInProgress || !canClassify) {
        console.log("scenario 2");
        return;
      }

      const ccce = window.ccce;

      if (!ccceValues || !ccce) {
        throw new Error("Unable to classify - no values or not initialised");
        console.log("scenario 3");
      }

      setClassifyInProgress(true);

      const classificationParameters = {
        ...ccceValues,
        ...DEFAULT_EMBED_PROPS,
      };

      ccce.classify(
        classificationParameters,
        handleResult,
        handleCancelClassify
      );
    },
    [
      classifyInProgress,
      canClassify,
      ccceValues,
      handleResult,
      handleCancelClassify,
    ]
  );

  return {
    allowForClassification: canClassify && !classifyInProgress,
    classifyInProgress,
    dataProfileId,
    embedID: EMBED_ID,
    handleCancelClassify,
    handleClassify,
    handleCloseModal,
    handleShowModal,
    isDebugMode,
    resultCode,
    shouldShowModal: showModal,
  };
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution

There's a lot that's missing in this code and there may be a better way to do this.  But here's what I came up with.

Instead of evaluating whether or not the input value is empty, we can evaluate whether or not it contains a character.

Replace this line:

```
const canClassify = Object.values(ccceValues).every(Boolean);
```

With these two lines:

```
const regex = new RegExp('\w', 'g');

const canClassify = Object.values(ccceValues).every(value => regex.test(value));
```

or this one line:

```
const canClassify = Object.values(ccceValues).every(value => /\w/g.test(value))
```

---

#### Why That Line?

I arrived at that solution by working backwards.  Here's all the steps that I took through the code to arrive at the right place.

```
allowForClassification: canClassify && !classifyInProgress,
```

`allowForClassification` is `true` if `canClassify` is `true` and `classifyInProgress` is `false`.  We don't want to classify if we are already performing a classification.  That makes sense.  So it's the `canClassify` value that we care about.

```
const { canClassify, ccceValues } = getCcceValues(object);
```

`canClassify` comes from the `getCcceValues` function, and it's value may depend on the value of `object`.

```
const { object, form } = useFormObjectContext();
```

`object` comes from some external hook which is a dead end for me because I can't see that code.  But note that there *might* be some alternative solution here.

```
const canClassify = Object.values(ccceValues).every(Boolean);
```

`.every(Boolean)` has the same meaning as writing it out longform `.every(value => Boolean(value))`.  `canClassify` is `true` if every value of `ccceValues` is `true` when cast to a `Boolean`.  Which means that the value is anything other than: `false`, `0`, `-0`, `0n`, `""`, `null`, `undefined`, `NaN`. ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy))

```
const ccceInput: $Shape<CcceInput> = {};

const ccceValues = object.attributeCollection.questions.reduce(
    (acc, attribute) => {
      const fieldEntry = ccceBeInformedFieldMap.get(attribute.key);

      if (fieldEntry) {
        acc[fieldEntry] = attribute.value;
      }

      return acc;
    },
    ccceInput
);
```

`ccceValues` is  bit complex.  It created by an [array .reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) operation. It starts with an initial value of `ccceInput` which is an empty object `{}`.  At each step of the iteration, it maybe sets one property on that object.  The final value is the object after a bunch of properties have been set.

The arguments in the callback are `acc` -- the object that we are building, and `attribute` -- the current element of the `questions` array.  The key that we are setting is `fieldEntry` and the value is `attribute.value`.

Remember that `canClassify` checks if all *values* are "truthy".  So the key doesn't matter.  We only care about the value (`attribute.value`).

---

#### Why That Code?

But working backwards, what we learning is that when `canClassify`/`allowForClassifiation` is `true` in cases where you want it to be `false`, **it's because there are values where `Boolean(attribute.value)` is `true` when you want it to be `false`**.  Why is that?

I'm going to make a logical assumption that the `attribute.value` variable contains the string that the user has typed in the box.

Remember what I said earlier about `Boolean` casting.  The empty string `''` is `false` and all other strings are `true`.  So if there is at least one box in `object.attributeCollection.questions` where the user hasn't entered anything, then `allowForClassification` will be `false` because `attribute.value` will be `''`.

As soon as the user hits the spacebar in the last box, the `attribute.value` becomes `' '`. **This string has a `Boolean` value of `true`**, so `allowForClassification` is now `true`.

But you want to apply a different ruleset.  You want to consider a value as `true` if and only if it contains at least one letter.  We can check that using a simple [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).  I'm not sure of your exact ruleset (Are numbers ok? What about underscores? What about accented/non-Latin characters?), so you might need to tweak the regex.  But this should get you 99% of the way there.

```
const regex = new RegExp('\w', 'g');
// can also be written as: const regex = /\w/g;
```

I am using the `\w` alphanumeric [character class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Character_Classes) and the `g` global match [flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/RegExp#parameters) to match any alphanumeric character anywhere in a string.

To check if a string matches this regex, use the [`.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) method.

```
const hasCharacter = regex.test(someString);
```

We want to use this function in the `.every()` callback of `canClassify` instead of the `Boolean` constructor function.  So we write:

```
const canClassify = Object.values(ccceValues).every(value => regex.test(value));
```